# Android phones and how they switch from mobile data and wifi automatically

Tags: android, network-programming, sms, wifi

How do phones choose which to prioritize when wifi and mobile data are on? Would love to know what governs the decision on this like the code or the drivers on the android phone.

Currently working on a project focused on building an app capable of failing over from a WiFi connection to a different line like SMS network if the internet line goes down. Looking to help disaster management institutions with the resiliency of their communication.

Comment: please accept an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android connectivity frameworks allow the apps to get a network connection regardless of the underlying physical connection. Android decides the connection type based on efficiency and availability. WiFi is the most efficient, cheap and good for battery so it always has priority. Unless either WiFi is not available or there is no internet connection. Then the system will try LTE, HSPA, 3G and 2G in that order (because of efficiency).

There is no way for your app to request a specific requirement from the system (wifi only or 3g only). The connection strategy is system-wide and used by all apps similarly. Instead, it is up to you to implement the disaster recovery. That is, you need to monitor the connection method. Apps like Spotify which need WiFi work the same. If the preferred connection is not available, notify the user or wait until it changes.

Google has [a very good seminar](https://dl.google.com/io/2009/pres/W_0300_CodingforLife-BatteryLifeThatIs.pdf) on this which I think will help you implement disaster recovery.

Comment: Wow! thank you. That's a lot of information, I'll take this in high regard good sir.